# How to reset keyboard view from 'symbols' to 'alphabet' programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView and I am listening to a UIButton event to take action on the text inside this textView:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked {
    NSString *text = myTextView.text;
    //Do some work with the text.
    myTextView.text = @""; //reset the textView.
}
```

I don't want the textView to `resignFirstResponder`. The problem I am facing is: When the last entered character was a symbol, the keyboard is stuck on that view and is not reset to the default keyboard alphabetic view, as is the behavior in messaging app and other apps too. How do I reset the keyboard programmatically in this method?

This may be a repeat question for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005738/uitextview-does-not-seem-to-implement-reloadinputviews). But the answer doesn't seem to work for me.

This is the accepted answer:

```
[editingField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[editingField reloadInputViews];
```

And this is the last comment:

> OK, apparently declaring it as a UITextView instead of a UIResponder affects how it behaves during runtime. That is literally the only change I made and it works now. Thanks.

But I can't seem to understand what the small change was that made it work, since I am still struggling with the issue.

I have already tried `resignFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder`, but in quick succession, the scrollableView behind is not set according to `keyboardWillShow` event. I have also tried `[textView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault]` but there is no change still.

Is there any API method that does this thing (like the keyboard is reset on clicking 'space' automatically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hack that I used was to use a hidden textField to reload the inputView.

Code:

```
UITextField *hiddenTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
[superView addSubview:hiddenTextField];

[hiddenTextField becomeFirstResponder];
[hiddenTextField reloadInputViews];
[textView_ becomeFirstResponder];

[hiddenTextField removeFromSuperview];
[hiddenTextField release];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use a temporary text field.  I just `resignFirstResponder` and immediately `becomeFirstResponder` on the very textview.  If the two calls are done immediately one right after the other, no keyboard sliding animation occurs.

So my buttonClicked function would look like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked {
    NSString *text = myTextView.text;
    //Do some work with the text.
    myTextView.text = @""; //reset the textView.

    // Reset keyboard back to QWERTY side
    [myTextView resignFirstResponder];
    [myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

As a side note, unfortunately, even though no animation occurs, the keyboard notifications (eg. `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`, etc) still get called.  I simply set a flag before I `resignFirstResponder` to notify my keyboard hide/show notification callbacks to skip execution.  And after I `becomeFirstResponder`, I clear that flag so when the keyboard does actually slide away, the notification callbacks can execute properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
[self.textField reloadInputViews];
```