# Change keyboard type of UITextField when go to another screen

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have UiTextField, when editing I change keyboard to emoji. then I go back and open another text view from another screen. but it shows emoji keyboard instead of default keyboard. please help me to fix this issue. thanks

Comment: please add this code  [textfield setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet]

Comment: Check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748973/how-to-reset-keyboard-view-from-symbols-to-alphabet-programatically

Comment: thank you @Rose for your feedback :) its working by setting keyboard type to UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set the keyboardType for the UITextField

```
 [textfield setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet]
```

Comment: hey Rose this doesn't work for UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress. any idea how to fix ?

Comment: check with [textfield setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress]

Comment: I tried by setting UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress. but its show emoji.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can fix it. It's up to the user to decide what keyboard they want visible and the setting applies across all apps, not just within your own app.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the Apple's [**documentation**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) to see in detail for keyboard implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Set keyboard types

```
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
```

These are the keyboard return types,

```
   UIKeyboardTypeDefault,
   UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,
   UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,
   UIKeyboardTypeURL,
   UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,
   UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,
   UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,
   UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,
   UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,
   UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,
   UIKeyboardTypeWebSearch
```

Check Apple Libaray , [Input KeyBoard Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/returnKeyType)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but the thing is I change keyboard to emoji. then I go back and open another text view from another screen. but it shows emoji keyboard instead of default keyboard. How do I get rid of emoji keyboard ?