# UITextField no longer reloads keyboardType after reloadInputViews call

Tags: ios8, xcode6

In iOS 7, I could change the keyboard type while it is the `firstResponder` (on the fly):

```
if (textField.text.length > 2) {

    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
}
else
{
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
}

[textField reloadInputViews];

// (Omitting some efficiency stuff to keep example to bare bones)
```

This no longer works under Xcode 6/iOS 8. The documentations mostly reflect changes regarding *custom* keyboard.

Using resign/become first responder is (still) working:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];

// Make keyboard change

[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

But it just feels like an overkill. It's tearing and rebuilding a wall, just to change a picture on it.

There is a related post here:
[UITextView does not seem to implement reloadInputViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005738/uitextview-does-not-seem-to-implement-reloadinputviews)

But it seems that the solution (in a comment) is "*apparently declaring it as a UITextView instead of a UIResponder affects how it behaves during runtime. ... and it works now*"

In my case it *is* a `UITextField`, and I tried to cast to `UITextView` just in case. No go.

I'll mention again that it *is* working well under iOS7 / Xcode5.

I don't really know if this is a 'beta' issue with Xcode 6, or a design change in iOS 8.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem in iOS8 with Xcode 6 beta 7.

Comment: reloadInputViews fails to do anything under iOS8 (on a device) running an app created in XCode 5.1.1. Works fine in iOS7.

Comment: The problem was not fixed until iOS 8.1

Answer (score 7):

I found the same issue. It is better to check whether the textField is already the firstResponder or not.

```
[textField reloadInputViews]; // does not work on iOS8 !

if ([textField isFirstResponder]) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Not a clean way though, but it works.

Comment: @bauerMusic: this answer solved a real-world problem. What did you do?

Comment: @adnan: thank you for a succinct solution to this iOS bug/change

Comment: @bauerMusic, I understand your point. But the fact is on iOS8 it does not work as it's supposed to be. My solution is based on hours of trial as I needed it to work at any cost! And it just works. I do not understand what is the problem? !!

Comment: @adnan Did you not see I have this "solution" in my original question? Quote (from MY original question): "_Using resign/become first responder is (still) working ... But it just feels like an overkill._". My question was if there was **ANOTHER** way. As I stated, I already know what you suggest, I wrote it so someone won't repeat it (as you just did). **Moreover**, there is (as I stated) no need to check if `textField` is firstResponer, it is. I ask how to do this without `resignFirstResponder` and your answer is use `resignFirstResponder`. Ok, thanx.

Answer (score 5):

I found that this works when the textfield is first responder:

```
[self.textField reloadInputViews];
[self.textField setText:@" "];
[self.textField setText:@""];
```

Comment: Actually, that's documented: "The first responder can reload the input and accessory views by calling the reloadInputViews method of UIResponder." - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html

Comment: Although both answers above are kind of a hack, but i find this one solved my problem:
[self.textField reloadInputViews];
NSString *originalText = self.textField.text;
[self.textField setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", originalText, @" "]];
[self.textField setText:originalText];

thanks