# UITextView doesn't switch input toolbar to custom keyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios9, xcode7, xcode7-beta6

iOS9 Xcode7 beta6: I'm trying to switch between keyboards (custom/default) for `UITextView` by using `reloadInputViews()`. Changing `UIKeyboardType` and `UIKeyboardAppearance` by calling `reloadInputViews()` works perfectly. Also following code works well under iOS8.

This implies that textView is already a first responder:

```
private func showCustomKeyboard() {
    textView.inputView = customKeyboardView
    textView.reloadInputViews()
}

private func showDefaultKeyboard() {
    textView.inputView = nil
    textView.reloadInputViews()
}
```

Things like the following have made no effect and also they look like overkill:

```
textView.inputView.resignFirstResponder()
textView.inputView.becomeFirstResponder()
textView.inputView = customKeyboardView
textView.reloadInputViews()
```

I found a couple of related questions on SO but no one of them doesn't have to do with iOS9 and as I said before it does work in iOS8.

Have anyone come across this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was related to a simulator with iOS9 on the board and eventually has been fixed with unchecking `Keyboard -> Connect -> Hardware Keyboard`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to change the order? Because you dismiss and after that show a keyboard again. Does it make sense?:

```
textView?.inputView.resignFirstResponder() // dismiss keyboard
textView?.inputView.becomeFirstResponder() // show keyboard
textView?.inputView = customKeyboardView // reassign new keyboard
textView?.reloadInputViews() // reload keyboard
```

Try:

```
textView?.inputView.resignFirstResponder() // dismiss keyboard
textView?.inputView = customKeyboardView // reassign new keyboard
textView?.reloadInputViews() // reload keyboard
textView?.inputView.becomeFirstResponder() // show keyboard
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense because reloadInputViews should be called while an object is a first responder. In all my examples I imply that a textView is already a first responder.

Comment: Tell me a reason to make `resignFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder` after that?

Comment: The reason is to force reloading of textView properties and it helps in some cases as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546339/uitextfield-no-longer-reloads-keyboardtype-after-reloadinputviews-call/26066823#26066823
In your example Apple's documentation says the following about reloadInputViews: "If the current object is not the first responder, this method has no effect." unfortunately.