# Animating an `inputView` Keyboard Transition

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

`UITextField` has an [`inputView`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20740874/2547229) property that can be used to specify a custom keyboard. Clearing this to `nil` provides the default keyboard.

If the `UITextField` is the first responder, no change occurs on setting `inputView`, but by calling [`[textField reloadInputView]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4005738/2547229) the keyboard change will happen immediately.

I'd like to be able to switch between two different input approaches. The interface to trigger this will be a `UISegmentedView` installed as the `UITextField`'s `inputAccessoryView`.

I've got this working, but the transition is very abrupt. Partly because the spinner and keyboard I transition between have different sizes on the iPad.

I've found that is I wrap an animation block around `reloadInputView`, I will get a smooth  animation between the two keyboard's view frames. Unfortunately there is a visual judder because the transition is not animated:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3 animations:^()
{
    [firstResponder reloadInputViews];
}];
```

Alternatively, if I wrap the reload in a transition, I can get a nice cross fade, but I don't get smooth frame changes:

```
[UIView transitionWithView: keyboardWindow
                  duration: 0.3
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations: ^(){ [firstResponder reloadInputViews]; }
                completion: nil];
```

(In the second code block I obtained `keyboardWindow` from `self.window` because this view is installed as the `UITextField`'s `inputAccessoryView` which is ultimately nested under the keyboard's window.)

What I'd like is to animate **and** transition the input view reload. I tried placing reload in a transition in an animation, and I also tried placing the reload in an animation in a transition – neither seemed to help.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `resignFirstResponder` to make the input view disappear  and then invoke `becomeFirstResponder`, after a delay, to make the keyboard appear and vice versa.

The following sets to inputView after resigning the normal keyboard.

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(1 * (NSEC_PER_SEC/3)))

textField.resignFirstResponder()

dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     self.textField.inputView = currentInputView
     self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

This sets to keyboard.

```
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     self.textField.inputView = nil
     self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Thanks – I don't want to resign the hide the keyboard and then reveal it again, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to successfully animate changes to an `inputView` without any glitches by:

1. Adding the new `inputView` as a subview of the existing `inputView` and then
2. Switching the `UIControl`'s `inputView` to the custom `inputView` after your choice of animation is complete.

As an example, here's how to quickly fade in a custom `inputView`:

```
//start the view as invisible
_customInputView.alpha = 0.0f;

//add the custom inputView as a subview of the existing inputView
[self.inputView addSubview:_customInputView];

//animate the opacity change
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f 
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         _customInputView.alpha = 1.0f;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //switch the UIControl's inputView
                         self.inputView = _customInputView;
                     }];
```

Comment: That sounds like a good approach. Thanks. I'm not in a position to test this at the moment, but you get a +1 from me :-)